# Можно ли в Visual Studio собирать проект на лету?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, iis

При компиляции и запуске проекта ASP.NET MVC Core часть .cs файлов блокируется студией и что б изменить код- надо "выключать сборку", изменять код, заново компилировать и запускать изменённый проект, затрачивая время.

Можно ли на лету после изменения .cs файла собрать проект и тут же увидеть в браузере обновлённые данные, не перезапуская весь IIS ?

Comment: Можно если использовать компьютер в качестве веб-сервера. Не путать с IIS Express, который запускает VS. Если интересно - напишу подробный ответ.

Comment: @"Vadim Prokopchuk" , да, напишите пожалуйста. Я впринципи понял Нужно IIS поставить и проект прикрутить к нему и потом сборку собрать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, если использовать компьютер в качестве локального веб-сервера. Не путать с IIS Express, который открывает Visual Studio при запуске проекта.

Следует заметить что компонент IIS включен как часть установки Windows как для сервера, так и для рабочих машин. Каждая версия OS Windows предлагает свою версию IIS: Windows 8 - IIS 8, Windows 7 - IIS 7/7.5

---

Чтобы установить его, необходимо выполнить следующие действия:

1. Открыть панель управления
2. Открыть "Программы"
3. Открыть "Включение или отключение компонентов Windows".
4. Выбрать Internet Information Services (Службы IIS)
5. Убедитесь, что вы выбрали поддержку ASP.NET.

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого раскройте узел Службы Интернета --> Компоненты разработки приложений --> ASP.NET (Internet Information Services --> World Wide Web Services --> Application Development Features --> ASP.NET) Если вы хотите использовать поддержку IIS в Visual Studio, которая позволяет вам создавать виртуальные каталоги IIS непосредственно в диалоговом окне New Web Site, вам нужно выбрать пункт «Совместимость управления IIS 6» в разделе «Средства управления веб-сайтом» (Web Management Tools --> IIS 6 Management Compatibility).

6. Ok
7. Убедитесь, что IIS активен: открыть `localhost:80` в браузере. Ниже показана стандартная страница.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
8. Установить SQL Server и разрешить подключения
9. Открыть Visual Studio с права администратора и создать виртуальный каталог для приложения: ПКМ по проекту --> Свойства --> Веб --> В разделе серверы выбрать "Локальный IIS" --> Нажать "Создать виртуальный каталог".
   Проект будет доступен по адресу указанному в графе `URL-адрес проекта`

После написания кода собираем проект `Ctrl+Shift+B` и перезагружаем страницу в браузере.

---

**Для отладки**

1. Запускаем Visual Studio с правами администратора
2. Жмем кнопку присоединиться (вверху на панельке, зеленая)
3. Ставим галочку на "Показать процессы, запущенные всеми пользователями"
4. Ищем процесс с названием "w3wp.exe"
5. Жмем "Присоединиться"